# Hibernate 4.x - Inserting Clob as String to database (Oracle - MySql)

Tags: java, hibernate, clob

I recently upgraded from Hibernate 3.x to 4.x, I used  [this article](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html/Migration_Guide/Migrate_Your_Hibernate_33x_Application_to_Hibernate_4x.html) as a reference.

I am facing a problem when inserting Clob data as a String to the database, my application runs on (Oracle - MySql - MSSQL) databases. This is my hibernate domain:

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "LargeText" )
public String getLargeText() {
    return largeText;
}

public void setLargeText(String largeText) {
    this.largeText = largeText;
}
```

When I try to insert the object to the database, this exception is being thrown:

```
SEVERE: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(ILjava/io/Reader;J)V
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.ClobTypeDescriptor$4$1.doBind(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:124)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:90)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:286)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:281)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:56)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2857)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3121)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
at com.damaris.threeg.dal.userManagement.hibernate.dao.impl.AbstractDao.save(AbstractDao.java:75)
at com.damaris.threeg.dal.documentManagement.hibernate.dao.impl.FDITemplateDaoImpl.saveFDITemplate(FDITemplateDaoImpl.java:76)
at com.damaris.threeg.documentManagement.manager.impl.FDITemplateManagerImpl.saveFDITemplate(FDITemplateManagerImpl.java:51)
at com.damaris.threeg.documentManagement.service.impl.FDITemplateServiceImpl.saveFDITemplate(FDITemplateServiceImpl.java:50)
at com.damaris.threeg.web.documentManagement.web.fdiTemplate.controller.FDITemplateController.saveFDITemplate(FDITemplateController.java:769)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Please post full stack trace

Comment: have you tried with `Length=999999` to `getLargeText()`? eg. `@Column(name = "LargeText", Length=999999)`

Comment: @Amogh, yes I tried and I got the same exception.

Comment: Ohh May I know which application server are you using, Tomcat 6 or 7 or ...?

Comment: Ok, by looking exception I guess it's related to `tomcat-dbcp` and DB driver (version). Tomcat doc says Tomcat 6 having DBCP 1.3 which provides support for JDBC 3.0. But as you are confirming that you are using Tomcat 7 so it will support to DBCP 1.4 which support JDBC 4.0. So can you confirm which JDBC version that you are using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75912/discussion-between-amogh-and-shahe).

Comment: I am using ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0 for oracle - and 5.1.35 for mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exception has various paths to solve it. This exception may occurs due to version to `Tomcat` server used along with `mysql-connector-java` version and also which dpcp implementation (`commons.dbcp or tomcat-dbcp`) is used and it's version of course.

According to [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75912/discussion-between-amogh-and-shahe) OA @Shahe is using Tomcat 7 along with mysql-connector-java version 5.1.35 which is latest one but @Shahe is using commons.dpcp with version 1.2.2 which was the problem.

**So updating the version of commons-dpcp to 1.4 or latest will solve the issue.**

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and commitment to solve the issue.